# Measuring Thread I/O in Java

Tags: java, io, profiling, monitoring, disk

I want to be able to measure thread I/O through code on my live/running application. So far the best (and only) solution I found is [this one](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3087741/Hooking-to-PerfMon-from-Java.htm) which requires me to hook directly into windows' performance monitor. However it seems very complex and there must be a simpler way to do this. I don't mind writing different code for Windows & Linux, to be honest I was expecting it.

Thanks for you help

Update:

So what I mean by Disk I/O is: If you open windows resource monitoring and go to the disk tab you can look at each process that is running and lock at the avg read/write of B/Sec over the last minute. I want to get the same data but per thread

Comment: Do you mean file I/O from your threads or do you mean data traffic between threads or something else? Please define *thread I/O*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Hyperic [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar). It is a cross-platform native resource Java API.

The class [FileSystemUsage](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DOUGM/hyperic-sigar-1.6.3-src/docs/javadoc/org/hyperic/sigar/FileSystemUsage.html) gives you a bunch of stats about file system usage (obvious...) such as

- Disk Queue
- Disk Writes / Disk Bytes Written
- Disk Reads / Disk Reads Written

Most of them are cumulative, but you just compute a delta every *n* seconds to get a rate.

There's also a javaagent for profiling/monitoring file IO called [JPicus](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Java/JPicus?bc=true). I have not looked at it in a while, but it may be useful.